# Compiling with Compass - File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: css, import, compilation, sass

I'm trying to use Compass for a project but it's making me want to tear my hair out.
When I compile my SCSS I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeSR9.png) error.

The full CSS it compiles is as follows:

```
/*
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: partials/reset.
   Load paths:
     Compass::SpriteImporter
     C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass
     C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
    on line 2 of C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass/main.scss

1: @import 'compass';
2: @import 'partials/reset';
3: @import '/partials/fonts';
4: @import '/partials/mediaqueries';
5:     
6: body {
7:     font-family: mouse-deco, sans-serif;

Backtrace:
C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass/main.scss:2
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:66:in     `rescue in import'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:294:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in `visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:173:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:180:in `visit_root'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:151:in `visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:17:in `block in render'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:29:in `with_import_scope'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-import-once-1.0.5/lib/compass/import-once/engine.rb:16:in `render'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:486:in `update_stylesheet'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:214:in `block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:208:in `update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.0/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:291:in `watch'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:46:in `watch!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:41:in `perform'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `call'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.1/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: partials/reset.\A        Load paths:\A          Compass::SpriteImporter\A          C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass\A          C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets\A         on line 2 of C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass/main.scss\A \A 1: @import 'compass';\A 2: @import 'partials/reset';\A 3: @import '/partials/fonts';\A 4: @import '/partials/mediaqueries';\A 5:     \A 6: body {\A 7:     font-family: mouse-deco, sans-serif;"; }
```

I'm hoping that it's an easy fix, but I'm struggling to see what the error is. Is it the gem itself or is it caused by my SCSS code?

Comment: Does the path to your partials look like this: `C:/Users/Tom.PC/lp/sass/partials/_reset.scss`?

Comment: Yeah, that's the file path. I have the project folder, and inside that I have the sass cache folder, the CSS folder and then the SASS folder which has the partials folder inside.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change

```
@import 'partials/reset';
```

into

```
@import '/partials/reset';
```

like it's already for the other files for the partials-folder.
It's only a guess as it's not clear where you locate your `sass_dir`, e.g.

```
sass_dir = "sass"
```

in your `config.rb`, but you could just give it a try.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with the / in front of it. If I remove the reset import, the next import gives an error. It only compiles when there's no imports. Sass dir is "sass" in my config.

Comment: So did the error change? It's possible that you now have to adjust all paths to start like ../partials/ etc, at least they have to start from the same root. Should just depend on your setup.

Comment: The partials folder is inside the SCSS folder. When I move the files I am importing into the same folder as my SCSS, the imports work fine i.e.     @import 'reset'; Am I just being an idiot and putting the wrong file path?

Comment: Glad it's working for you now. Though it still looks like there's an issue with some import/path/etc, at least you get your css.

Answer (score -1):

You must add option to your sass compiler `--compass` like  `--sourcemap=none` and will be fine

Comment: If you look at the provided image, the OP is using the compass command.  Also, the error indicates that the compass directory is being searched.